# Why is subplot changing the color of my image?

Tags: python, subplot

I am trying to extract a frame from video and display each frame as an image. For comparison I tried subplotting. The read RGB image is different when plotted. Where could I be possibly wrong?

```
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(file1)
num_frames = int(vid.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3)
plt.ion()
for i in range(num_frames):
    f,img = vid.read(i)
    cv2.imshow("V",img)
```

the rgb image is read correctly but when

```
for i in range(num_frames):
    f,img = vid.read(i)
    ax[0].imshow(img)
    ax[1].imshow(img)
    ax[2].imshow(img)
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.01)
```

the color of the displaying images is changed 
[subplot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbDJ5.png) [cv2 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDVn7.png)

Comment: it is likely to do with image displaying in BGR rather than RGB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
ax[0].imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
```

Comment: The reason why it is happening is because you are using imread from cv2 for reading the image which reads images in BGR format and you are displaying image by pyplot from matplotlib which displays image in  RGB format, hence there is a reversal in the channels of Red and Blue. Hope its clear now